# iOS: UIImageView backgroundcolor somehow reset after setting it in viewWillAppear

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, uiimageview, mkmapview

Very strange problem. I set the `backgroundcolor` of an `UIImageView` depending on the value of a attribute in my `coredata` entity Category. This category can be changed when clicking on the Category in the `UINavigationController`. So after changing the category and "popping" back in the `UINavigationController` hierarchy, I want the `backgroundcolor` to be adjusted. At the beginning I had this code only in the `viewWillAppear` method. And like that it first always set the new color but then switched back to the original state before. Now I "fixed" it by placing the code in both, `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear`. But I don't like doing this without knowing why. Any idea where the error is?

Here is the current code:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    //First the category name and pin
    //ATTENTION: I don't know why but without having this placed in viewWill and viewDidAppear, this wouldn't work..
    if(self.poi.belongsToCategory){
        self.categoryLabel.text = self.poi.belongsToCategory.name;
        self.categoryLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        self.pinColorImageView.backgroundColor = [POICategory getColorForPinColorType:[self.poi.belongsToCategory.pinColor intValue]];
    } else {
        self.categoryLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"0_category_uncategorized", nil);
        self.pinColorImageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        self.categoryLabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    }
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    //First the category name and pin
    if(self.poi.belongsToCategory){
        self.categoryLabel.text = self.poi.belongsToCategory.name;
        self.categoryLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        self.pinColorImageView.backgroundColor = [POICategory getColorForPinColorType:[self.poi.belongsToCategory.pinColor intValue]];
    } else {
        self.categoryLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"0_category_uncategorized", nil);
        self.pinColorImageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        self.categoryLabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    }

    //And then place the pin on the map and zoom
    [self.mapView addAnnotation:self.pin];
    [self focusOnPin];
}
```

Comment: Maybe it is because you call `[super viewWillAppear:animated];` and `[super viewDidAppear:animated];` Do you do some color changes in the super class?

Comment: How are you changing the belongsToCategory property? Could it be getting set after `viewWillAppear` is executed. i.e. Do you pop the controller and set the category after that call or before? If so the color could be getting set to the previous color in `viewWillAppear` then the new color in `viewDidAppear.` Worth describing how you pop and change the category.

Comment: Well I only call super but I do not do any color changes in the super calss.

Comment: @RoryMcKinnel what happened to your answer?

Comment: @Mikael Sorry, not sure I understand. Answer to what? My last comment was to ask for more information on how the `belongsToCategory` is set with a theory on what is going wrong. I suspect that `viewWillAppear` is probably being called, (unless @MichiZH can confirm it is definitely not entered), and the issue is a result of the timing of calls as noted in my last comment. However I have seen no updates since asking, hence had nothing else to say.

Comment: I'm sorry I got confused with another question. My bad...

Answer (score 0):

viewWillAppear is not called when you pop back to the viewController when embeded in a nav controller. One approach for you is to only show it in viewDidAppear but my guess is that it will cause a little flicker that is not very nice.

The most elegant solution is to add a protocol to the second view controller. Have the presenting view controller register as the delegate. Then the presenting view controller can implement a delegate method to change the color and only pop the presented view controller once that is done.

Let me know if you need some code to get you started.

Comment: `viewWillAppear` is called when you pop back from one controller to another. This is why you sometimes have to check if it has been called because the controller is being pushed/presented or being exposed as a result of a pop/dismiss.

Comment: Yes I agree. Perhaps not the best choice of words. Bottom line in his case willAppear is not called.

Comment: I don't understand, you somehow contradict each other don't you? But thanks for the protocol advice I think that's the way to go.

Comment: I don't think we are contradicting each other is just depends how your stack is structured and in your case viewWillAppear is apparently not called. Either way it does not matter you should use presentViewController and create a protocol... Happy coding!